# Aggregate the results of a jq query into a single array

Tags: json, jq

I have an input file that has independent JSON objects (i.e. not an array) and I want to filter a few fields from each of them and create an array with the resulting elements. It's basically a list of log statements in JSON format.

I am using `jq` for this, and it's working great, except that I can't aggregate all resulting objects into a single array.

The input is something like this:

```
{"name":"myname", "environment":"staging", "email":"email1@example.com", "time":"2017-04-02T05:00:00.046Z"}
{"name":"myname", "environment":"staging", "email":"email2@example.com", "time":"2017-02-02T05:00:00.046Z"}
...
{"name":"myname", "environment":"staging", "email":"email3@example.com", "time":"2017-10-02T05:00:00.046Z"}
{"name":"myothername", "environment":"staging", "time":"2017-10-02T05:00:00.046Z"}
```

(Note that the last entry has no `email` field, and thus it will return a `null` value if not filtered)

From this list of objects I'd like to get only the fields `email` and `time`, and ignore the rest, so I used the following `jq` query:

`jq '{email: (.email | values), time: (.time | values)}' input.json`

Note that I use the `values` filter because the log messages are mixed, so not all json objects have the `email` field, so I ignore those.

My problem is now that even though I get the desired result, I get a list again, and I'd like an array.

I.e. I get something like

```
{"email":"email1@example.com", "time":"2017-04-02T05:00:00.046Z"}
{"email":"email2@example.com", "time":"2017-02-02T05:00:00.046Z"}
...
{"email":"email3@example.com", "time":"2017-10-02T05:00:00.046Z"}
```

And I would like it like:

```
[
    {"email":"email1@example.com", "time":"2017-04-02T05:00:00.046Z"},
    {"email":"email2@example.com", "time":"2017-02-02T05:00:00.046Z"},
    ...,
    {"email":"email3@example.com", "time":"2017-10-02T05:00:00.046Z"}
]
```

---

I've tried several different things but I usually end up with the error `Cannot index array with string "email"` which tells me I'm doing something wrong with the array operations.

I tried wrapping the query in `map()`, i.e. `map({.userEmail, .time})`, tried slurping the data with `-s` and I tried using the `|+` and `|=` operators.

I have also tried wrapping the query inside array brackets like `[{email: (.email|values), time:.time }]`, but I get the same resulting objects except each of them is wrapped inside an array by itself, i.e.

```
[{"email":"email1@example.com", "time":"2017-04-02T05:00:00.046Z"}]
[{"email":"email2@example.com", "time":"2017-02-02T05:00:00.046Z"}]
...
[{"email":"email3@example.com", "time":"2017-10-02T05:00:00.046Z"}]
```

It seems like it's probably an easy thing to do, or a common operation at least, but I am failing to find the correct query.

What is the correct way then, of aggregating the query results into an array, when the input is not an array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even better...

1. Based on your sample data, your basic filter can be simplified to `{email, time}`
2. In general, it is better to avoid "slurping" the input (e.g. to save memory).  This can be accomplished in your case by using `inputs` with the -n command-line option.

Putting it all together:

```
jq -n '[inputs | {email, time }]' input.json
```

If there are some inputs that you want to filter out, you could use `select`, e.g.

```
jq -n '[inputs | select(.email) | {email, time } ]' input.json
```

Comment: Interesting!. So, if I understand correctly, the `-n` option is used to avoid reading any input at all, and instead we use the `inputs` filter. That seems to work but unfortunately it's still giving me one null value, which I would like to avoid. It's almost equivalent, except for the null part.

Comment: Apparently your actual data contains some items that differ from the sample data.  So you will have to filter out the elements you don't want.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I didn't add it to the sample data. Basically, there are entries with no email but with the time field set, so in those cases I get a few entries with a time value but null for email, which I don't want. Unfortunately the shorthand version `{email, time}` does not support doing `{(email | values), time}`.
I just added an extra entry at the end, that has no `email` field to illustrate this. In any case, your solution is pretty good, except for this edge case that I didn't properly exemplify.

Answer (score 2):

After reading some more I found the result I wanted, which is a combination of the slurp operator and map.

I realized that the query

`jq -s 'map({email: (.email|values), time:.time })' input.json`

Would read all the input items *as an array* and then as [per the definition of map()](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions):

> For any filter x, map(x) will run that filter for each element of the input array, and return the outputs in a new array

So the two combined gave me the result I needed.